# Confusion on union and intersection of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I am studying set theory on my own, using the book of Enderton: *Elements of Set Theory*. My question is the following:

On Chapter $2$, the book discusses Arbitrary Unions and Intersections. It starts by treating a "general case", which is a set $A$ in which every $a_j$ in $A$ is also a set.

I understand the union operation, for example when we are looking at the union of $\cup \lbrace \lbrace 2,4,6 \rbrace, \lbrace 6,16,26\rbrace,\lbrace 0\rbrace \rbrace = \lbrace2,4,6,16,26,0\rbrace$.

Now suppose we want to compute $\lbrace a,b,c,d\rbrace$. The result in the book is $a\cup b \cup c\cup d$. What it confuses me is that the axiom says that the union **is** a set (s.t. etc.), the above operation is meaningless unless $a,b,c,d$ are sets themselves. Is this correct?

A similar question is the calculation in the book $\cap\lbrace a,b\rbrace =a\cap b$.

Comment: If $a,b,c,d$ are sets, then $a\cup b\cup c \cup d$ makes sense. If they are for instance numbers, it doesn't make sense. You can have the set $\{a,b,c,d\}$, which is the set containing the sets $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: Yes, for this to be true, $a,b,c,d$ should be set.

Comment: Ok, then it is my personal opinion that the book confuses with its notation. Thanks a lot!